# Why does my for loop stop following the conditions and return just 0 after first couple iterations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a data frame `df`. I am adding the last 120 rows at a time from beginning cell `i`, under the same column, and update the sum to the following cell (121th row). After that, the beginning cell becomes `i+1` and repeat. The problem with my code is for the first couple loops it works fine and the results are correct, but then it stops calculating based on the conditions and return just 0. What are the issues here?

```
cul_precip_120 = 0
counter_120 = 120
for i in range(1, len(df)): # starting day 367, which is first day in 1971
    
    cul_precip_120 = df.Precip.iloc[127 + counter_120: 247 + counter_120 : 1].sum() # 30 days from day 337 to day 366

    temp_120 = np.append(temp_120, cul_precip_120)

    counter_120 += 120
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see your loop , you will start seeing zeros the moment `iloc` arguments start: `127 + counter_120` , particularly the end: `247 + counter_120`, crosses beyond the length of the dataframe - `len(df)` . There is nothing to sum() beyond the last record.
I am not sure of your business logic but you can put a condition like inside the for loop -

```
if counter > len(df):
    break
```

Comment: Okay my bad for not explaining it more explicitly. So my data frame have the length of 19032 (days) from 1970 to 2021, and my logic is looking back the last 120 days in 1970 and add them to the first day of 1971, and go on. The loop actually iterates till 900ish days (length of data frame) and stop, but this is still way less than the length of data frame I have. So, I don't get why